# Android material design - shadow produced by windowElevation darkens on orientation change

Tags: android, material-design, shadow, orientation-changes, android-elevation

I have an activity whose window size is decreased as can be seen [here](http://postimg.org/image/ce29laqnj/) in google i/o 2014 app's screenshot. In the theme for this activity I have set windowElevation as follows:

```
<item name="android:windowElevation">8dp</item>
```

First time screen shows proper elevation effect - [check this](http://postimg.org/image/6hf6lybtr/), but on orientation change the shadow color darkens to black color - [check this](http://postimg.org/image/wveydrkz5/). Any idea how to prevent this?

Currently the top activity has fragment added for entire screen. If I remove the fragment & keep entire functionality in the activity itself then this issue does not occur.

Comment: Probably on orientation change your activity is adding another fragment on top of the already there fragment, thus causing an overlap of transparency and the effect that the color changed.

Comment: are you using a real device or emulator ?

Comment: @jvrodrigues No, I already checked this. I have a flag in activity to track if fragment is already added or not. On orientation change I retain this flag value using onSaveInstanceState() resulting in no fragment additions if already added.

Comment: @NadirB Real device Nexus 7

Comment: Shadows don't get darker unless they are overlaid. You are showing multiple elevated layers.

Comment: @alanv Single elevated window is there where I am adding fragment only first time.

Comment: Check using hierarchyviewer. The only way to get a shadow like that is to overlay multiple shadows.